# How to access data from JSON file using three js

Tags: json, graph, websocket, three.js

I am writing a code to plot a 3D graph. But I have written the data in code itself using an array now I want to pull the data from the JSON file and plot the data. How can it be done using three js?

Answer (score 0):

For reading a json file you could use d3.js, that will open the file and asynchronously will read the content and it will deserialize it into an object.

To use it, you only need to add the script to your code

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

and then in your code you'll be able to use this...

```
d3.json("/data/points.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

if the file path (full or relative) is right and the json is well formed, `data` will be an array of the objects contained in the json file.

You can find mode guidance here [d3js.org](https://d3js.org/)